# how to create a mirror of an instance?

Tags: instance, google-compute-engine, mirror

Using Google Compute Engine, how can I create a mirror of an instance? The instance is already created, but I need to create an identical mirror as a backup. Ideally, if something goes wrong in the original instance, the backup should automatically take over.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [snapshots](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#snapshots). You can take a snapshot of your instance and use it to c[reate a new disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#applying_snapshots) to spin up another instance.

Answer (score 1):

And if you're looking for a way to use snapshots as backup, you should take a look at [Compute Engine Persistent Disk Backups using Snapshots](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/persistent-disk-backups-using-snapshots.html).